# Use of 'local machine's IP' in iptables rule?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ansible

I have written port-forwarding `iptables` rules that I plan to roll-out to several machines in an automated way using [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html). However, the `POSTROUTING` chain rule requires a modification of the source address to be that of the local machine so the machine receiving the forwarded packets knows where to respond. The rule looks like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.11.2 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.11.1
```

That is, after using DNAT in `PREROUTING` to change the destination address to 192.168.11.2 (and `ACCEPT`ing it), I must then use `SNAT` to change the source address in the network header before sending the packet into the network.

Can this rule be written in such a way to specify symbolically that `--to-source` should be "the local machine's IP"? I accomplished this by compiling the necessary commands into a series of piped commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.11.2 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source $(ifconfig eth1 | grep -i "inet " | awk '{print $2}')
```

However, my intent is to generate an `iptables` configuration file and just roll that out to each machine if possible.

Answer (score 2):

iptables config scripts are just shell scripts. You can add the local ip address to a variable in the 'normal' way:

```
LOCALIP=`hostname -i`
```

and then replace any hard coded ip address instances with

```
$LOCALIP
```

Comment: Isn't `$(hostname -i)` usually 127.0.0.1 or some other localhost address?

Comment: not unless you've specifically added the FQDN to the hosts file

Comment: `hostname -i` on my Arch Linux machine returns `127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1`. My `/etc/hosts` file has two entries; both are `localhost.localdomain`.

Comment: You might need to use another method to discern the local ip (parsing the output of ifconfig for example) but the basic point remains. I did test the above on Ubuntu and Centos.

Comment: I did something similar originally. This is true if I am always writing iptable rules using the command interface. Do you know of a method for doing so using the iptables.rules file? On Arch this file is located at `/etc/iptables/iptables.rules`. My intent was to generate the identical iptables rule files and distribute them to the target machines.

Comment: I believe that file is the output of `iptables-save` and is not meant to be edited directly, simply invoked with `iptables-restore`

Comment: Fair enough. I originally was working with [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables) tutorial that showed manual editing on Ubuntu. The associated file was `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.

Comment: @sherrellbc Since you are using ansible, you should be able to use something like `{{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MASQUERADE target instead of SNAT.

You might want to read [Difference between SNAT and Masquerade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21967/difference-between-snat-and-masquerade) however, as MASQUERADE has an overhead.