# Route forwarded packets differently from outgoing

Tags: iptables, routing, iproute

I'm using iptables to forward and SRCNAT (specifically MASQUERADE) packets from a specific source. I want to route outgoing packets (initiated by this computer) differently from those being forwarded (different default route). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to mark the traffic in iptables and match an outbound route with policy routing:

let's say you have **gateway1** and **gateway2** on the same LAN...

```
ip route flush table 3
ip route add table 3 <lan net>
ip route add default via <gateway1>

ip route flush table 4
ip route add table 4 <lan net>
ip route add default via <gateway2>
```

Tag the traffic in iptables:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING   -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 3
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING   -s 10.1.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 4
```

You can match on anything you like, source address, destination address or port, etc...

Since you're explicitly rewriting the source IP in iptables rather than relying on a dynamic gateway IP you probably want to use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE.  See [Differences between SNAT and MASQUERADE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21967/difference-between-snat-and-masquerade#21968)

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add/edit "net.ipv4.ip_forward" option.

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

For inmediate changes run:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

iptables rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i input_dev -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o output_dev --src src_ip -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I need it to have a different default route. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Only create a virtual interface over output_dev (output_dev:0 for example) change the default route for this virtual interface and use it as output device on iptables rules.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Default routes are per routing table, not per interface

Comment: If you can provide me a working example I'll accept your answer and give you the bounty.

Comment: Bounty is insignifficant. I want to help you. :)
I can not obtain any result, but try changing the mac destination of forwarded paquests that it's ip destination is not a local ip. (use arptables for it).

Comment: What do you mean by different default route? there can be only one default. As @Pablo suggested, you should be able to create virtual interface and use "route add -net <ip> -dev <virt-intf>

Comment: There can be multiple within different routing tables.